# How do you make an MPEG4 out of a directory containing frames(PNG) using python and CUDA?

Tags: python, image, opencv, gpu, codec

I have used python and OPENCV with CPU to make a statement like this:

out = cv2.gpu.VideoWriter_GPU.VideoWriter_GPU('videoOut.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 15, size)

However, it is very slow since it is using the CPU.  How do you create a video with CUDA to use the GPU?

Comment: FFMPEG can be compiled with cuda support and it has python bindings, or you could just call ffmpeg binary

Comment: Rasjani, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.   Fortunately, I noticed that I compiled the OPENCV with FFMPEG and confirmed it is there and I'll get started with this approach.